# Regular Expression allow characters and 1 dot only between

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I want a regular expression which only allows a-z characters and 1 dot only **between** characters, not in the beginning or end of the string, here is what I've got:

```
var myRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z]*(\.{1}[a-zA-Z]*)?$/;
```

But it also allows the dot to be the first or the last character, how could I disallow dot in beginning or at the end of string?

The above code works in JS, how about the same regular expression in PHP with preg_match()?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*`means 0-many. If you use a `+` then this will force at least 1 character to appear before and after the dot. i.e.

```
var myRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z]+(\.{1}[a-zA-Z]+)?$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var myRegexp = /^[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?$/i;
```

Comment: you oversimplified it, this forces the dot to be present.